# Reading from a file, InputMismatchException

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File("data.txt"); // select file
    try{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); // set scanner to file
        try{
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){ 
    Employee employee = new Employee(); //create employee to hold data
            assignData(sc); //read data into employee
            employee.getGross(); //calculate gross pay
            addEmployee(employee);//assign employee to array
            }//end while
        }//end try2
        finally {
            sc.close(); // close file, saving resource usage
        }//end finally
    }//end try1
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static void assignData(Scanner input){ 
        //accept scanner
        //read necessary input for employee
        EmpID = input.next();****
        LastName = input.next();****
        FirstName = input.next();****
   (LINE 36)Hours = input.nextDouble();
        Rate = input.nextDouble();
    }
```

Data File contents

```
42345 Bruch Max 40 21.50 
23456 Elgar Eddie 43 20.0 
34567 Bach John 30 30 
12345 Wagner Rick 41 30 
88888 Mozart Wolfie 36 40 
65432 Chopin Fred 45 23.25 
72345 Strauss Butch 50 25
```

---

compiling, i get the error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at programassignment1c.Employee.assignData(Employee.java:36) (
at programassignment1c.ProgramAssignment1C.main(ProgramAssignment1C.java:44)
```

Java Result: 1

---

Line 36 in Employee class, is highlighted above, it is the nextDouble() What am i doing wrong?  Can doubles be scanned for even if they have no decimal place?

Writing this out by hand I see the scanner starting on: 42345 and it sets this to EmpID, then scanner advances past whitespace to

Bruch and it sets this to LastName, then scanner advances past whitespace to Max and it sets this to FirstName, then scanner advances past whitespace to 40 and should set this to Hours???? i am not following the scanner correctly?

Comment: You edited your question with `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. Which one is it? As you have it now, the scanning shouldn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: it still throws the same exception, i copied the wrong code, this code show the error i listed.

Comment: I just copy pasted what you have in your question and the scanner works fine. Please edit your answer with either the right code or the right exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use specific data type methods here :

```
    EmpID = input.nextLine();
     LastName = input.nextLine();
    FirstName = input.nextLine();
```

try using `nextInt/next` instead of `nextLine`.As `nextLine` will read the entire line and when you try to assign it to an `int` value it throws `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: `InputMismatchException` is an `Exception` thrown by `Scanner` not by the runtime or compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `nextLine()` instead of `next()` which reads (and skips but doesn't consume line separators) the line each time. You have

```
    EmpID = input.nextLine();
    LastName = input.nextLine();
    FirstName = input.nextLine();
(LINE 36)Hours = input.nextDouble();
    Rate = input.nextDouble();
```

So

```
42345 Bruch Max 40 21.50 // EmpID
23456 Elgar Eddie 43 20.0  // LastName 
34567 Bach John 30 30 // FirstName, but not the new line characters
12345 Wagner Rick 41 30 
88888 Mozart Wolfie 36 40 
65432 Chopin Fred 45 23.25 
72345 Strauss Butch 50 25
```

See comments.

The javadoc for `nextLine()` states

> This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line
>   separator at the end.

so the `nextDouble()` call is trying to read the line separator which isn't of type `double` and so throws an `InputMismatchException`.

You want each token on the line, use

```
EmpID = input.next();
LastName = input.next();
FirstName = input.next();
Hours = input.nextDouble();
Rate = input.nextDouble();
```

The javadoc for `next()` states

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern.

where the delimiter by default is

```
Pattern.compile("\\p{javaWhitespace}+");
```

ie. whitespace characters.

---

Java naming conventions dictate that variable names should start with a lowercase alphabetic character.

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` won't fit in your requirement(because **data in the file is separated by space not the new line**).

> Since It advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

So try this

```
public static void assignData(Scanner input)
{ 
        empID = input.nextInt();
        lastName = input.next();
        firstName = input.next();
        hours = input.nextDouble();
        rate = input.nextDouble();
 }
```

Note: I have changed your variables names to follow java naming convention.